Lee Introduction to Smooth Manifolds Problem 5-19

$\textbf{Problem 5-19.}$ Suppose $S\subseteq M$ is an embedded submanifold and $\gamma:J\to M$ is a smooth curve whose image happens to lie in $S$. Show that $\gamma'(t)$ is in the subspace $T_{\gamma(t)}S$ of $T_{\gamma(t)}M$ for all $t\in J$. Give a counterexample if $S$ is not embedded.


$\textbf{Corollary 5.30 (Embedded Case).}$ Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $S\subseteq M$ be an embedded submanifold. Then every smooth map $F:N\to M$ whose image is contained in $S$ is also smooth as a map from $N$ to $S$.


Now let $M$ be a smooth manifold, still with or without boundary. Our definition of tangent spaces leads to a natural interpretation of velocity vectors: given a smooth curve $\gamma:J\to M$ and $t_0\in J$, we define $\textbf{velocity of $\gamma$ at $t_0$}$ (Fig 3.9), denoted by $\gamma'(t_0)$ to be the vector $$\gamma'(t_0)=d\gamma\left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right\arrowvert_{t_0}\right)\in T_{\gamma(t_0)}M,$$
where $\left.d/{dt}\right\arrowvert_{t_0}$ is the standard coordinate basis vector in $T_{t_0}\mathbb{R}$.

Attempt: Because $S$ is an embedded submanifold and the image of $\gamma$ lies in $S$, we can consider $\gamma$ as a smooth curve from $J$ to $S$. Thus, $\gamma'(t)\in T_{\gamma(t)}S$.
For the counterexample, I was thinking of the figure-eight curve $\beta:(-\pi,\pi)\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\beta(t)=(\sin 2t,\sin t)$ because it intersects itself at 0. However, I am not sure if this is even correct or how to prove it.

What is $\gamma$ in the case of your attempted counterexample?

@TedShifrin I was thinking of the curve going through the origin. More explicitly, $\beta\arrowvert_{(a,b)}$ where $(a,b)\subseteq (-\pi,\pi)$.

Have you drawn a picture? What you just told me gives you a tangent vector to the submanifold, by definition, doesn’t it?

@TedShifrin Yes, I realized that it doesn't work. I drew a picture, and I think the curve at the top of the "8" is where it fails because the tangent plane is a horizontal line, but the velocity away from top of the "8" has a nonzero vertical component.

No. Why is this not an embedded submanifold?

@TedShifrin The figure-eight cannot have codimension 0 because it is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It cannot have discrete topology or else $\beta^{-1}(0,0)=0$ is open, so it cannot have codimension 2. It follows that it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{S}^1$. Since the figure-eight is compact, it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$. But removing a point (specifically (0,0)) makes the figure-eight disconnected but not for $\mathbb{S}^1$, so it cannot be an embedded submanifold.

Fine. Concentrate on the point that stops it from being embedded.

I might be wrong, but would the tangent plane at (0,0) be line with positive slope. However, if we let the curve be the bottom circular part of the "8", then its vector at the origin will be horizontal.

Write $M$ as the image of $\beta$. Note that $\beta(0)=(0,0)$ and
\begin{align*}
    d\beta_0\left(\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right\arrowvert_0\right)&=2\cos(0)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\right\arrowvert_{(0,0)}+\cos(0)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}\right\arrowvert_{(0,0)}\\
    &=2\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\right\arrowvert_{(0,0)}+\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}\right\arrowvert_{(0,0)}.
\end{align*}
Because $\beta$ is a local diffeomorphism in some neighborhood of 0, it follows that this is the basis for $T_{(0,0)}M$. Define $\gamma:(-\pi,\pi)\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$\gamma(t)=(\sin 2t,-\sin t).$$
Note that the image of $\gamma$ lies in $M$ and $\gamma(0)=(0,0)$. Repeating the same calculation as above, it follows that
$$\gamma'(0)=d\gamma\left(\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right\arrowvert_0\right)=2\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\right\arrowvert_{(0,0)}-\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}\right\arrowvert_{(0,0)}.$$
But $2\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\right\arrowvert_{(0,0)}-\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}\right\arrowvert_{(0,0)}$ is not generated by the basis for $T_{(0,0)}M$, so it is not in $T_{(0,0)}M$.
